# Scala - groupBy and count instances of each value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a DataFrame DF and I want to count the number of each txn under the 2 Categories (Cat1 and Cat2).

```
DF                                
+------------+-------+
|  Category  |  txn  | 
+-----===----+-------+  
|  Cat1      |   A   |  
|  Cat2      |   A   |
|  Cat1      |   B   |
|  Cat1      |   C   |
|  Cat2      |   D   |
|  Cat1      |   D   |
|  Cat2      |   C   |
|  Cat1      |   D   |
|  Cat1      |   A   |
|  Cat2      |   C   |
|  Cat1      |   D   |
|  Cat1      |   A   |
|  Cat2      |   B   |
|  Cat1      |   C   |
|  Cat2      |   D   |
+------------+-------+
```

Code:

```
DF.groupBy("category_name").agg(count("txn").as("txn_count")).show(false)
```

But this only give me the total count for each category.

Desired output: (the format doesn't matter, just need the count)

```
+------------+---------------------+
|  Category  |     txn_count       | 
+-----===----+---------------------+  
|  Cat1      | A(3),B(1),C(2),D(3) |  
|  Cat2      | A(1),B(1),C(2),D(2) |
+------------+---------------------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first group by both columns (using `count`) and then group by `Category` only (using `collect_list`):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val result = DF
  .groupBy("Category", "txn").count()
  .groupBy("Category").agg(collect_list(struct("txn", "count")) as "txn_count")

result.show(false)
// prints:
// +--------+--------------------------------+
// |Category|txn_count                       |
// +--------+--------------------------------+
// |Cat2    |[[D, 2], [C, 2], [B, 1], [A, 1]]|
// |Cat1    |[[D, 3], [C, 2], [B, 1], [A, 3]]|
// +--------+--------------------------------+
```